# Which recommender system approach is good with high sparsity in user?

Tags: recommender-system

I'm building a recommendation system, but my data has high sparsity.  In most of my data, each user gives one feedback, for one item. For example, I have 10 items and 15 users, I have 3 feedbacks, from 3 different users, and the scenario for others items is like:

[image: Example]

Is there a preferred approach to building a recommendation system with this kind of data?

Comment: Hello, Ali! Welcome to the site! The solution to sparsity is regularization, which means making assumptions. It would help to have metadata about the users and items too. The way you have currently set it up is amenable to matrix factorization, but with the ancillary data you can look into factorization machines.

Answer (score 0):

You're dataset seems fairly small for a recommendation system so I am not sure how these approaches with scale but you are looking to solve a collaborative filtering problem which is essentially a sparse matrix completion. I popular and effective method for doing this is [softImpute](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/mazumder10a.pdf).

For further resources here is a survey paper on [Top-N Recommender Systems via Matrix Completion](https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI16/paper/download/11824/11581).